# Multiple y-axes causing range to have too much padding

Tags: highcharts

When I plot a chart with one y-axis, the range padding is proper.

When I plot the same chart with an extra axis that has no data, there is too much padding.

```
yAxis: [
    {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Opens'
        }
    },
    {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Cumulative'
        },
        opposite: true
    }
],
```

I have both in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erhartford/q2trwc5a/).

Is there a setting I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set **`alignTicks: false`** in the option of `chart`:

```
chart: {
    type: 'column',
    alignTicks: false
}
```

You can see it in the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q2trwc5a/4/).

You can also use **`tickPositions`** to set the exact points you want the axis to show in your chart:

```
tickPositions: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q2trwc5a/2/).

If you want to set the positions dynamically you can use the **`tickPositioner`** function:

```
tickPositioner: function () {

    var positions = [],
    tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
    increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 5);

    for (tick; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
        positions.push(tick);
    }

    return positions;
}
```

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q2trwc5a/3/).

Answer (score 3):

You need to set [alignTicks](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks) as false.